# Best way to set up multiple urls for the same Wordpress site?

Tags: multisite, urls, directory

I have a portfolio site for all my art under a main url. The site houses all the different kinds of projects I do.  One of my main projects is a webcomic and I want the section of the site dedicated to it to have its own url or be accessible / searchable under the section specific url. It’s a separate brand. I don’t want to manage multiple websites separately if I can avoid it.

I’ve searched a fair bit and see there are multiple possible ways to approach this. I’m unsure what would be best for my use case ? What is the easiest implementation I should consider ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.